# How to add multiple values to an array in php

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create a new array using loop(foreach).

My array is looking like this :

```
$q_list = Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [subject_id] => 1
        [question] => Question No One
        [recordstatus] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [subject_id] => 1
        [question] => Question No Two
        [recordstatus] => 1
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [subject_id] => 1
        [question] => Question No Three
        [recordstatus] => 1
    )
)
```

I have done like this but not working :

```
foreach ($q_list as $key => $q) {
    $question[] = $q['question'];
    $question[] = $q['subject_id'];
}
```

Comment: Array name is `$question_list` but you trying to iterate `$q_list`

Comment: its my mistake actually $q_list is the actual array name

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: create a new array of all duplicate questions with its subject id . In the given array there are hundreds of records but for the test purpose i show only three records there are many duplicate entries

Comment: I don't understand your question properly, you need to elaborate more

Comment: how do you want the resulting array `$question` to look like, what `index=>value` should be stored once the loop completes? are you trying to get all the `question` and the `subject_id` into a separate array?

Comment: **Needs Debugging Details**

Answer (score 0):

This will group your array on subject_id.
I use subject_id as the key in a multidimensional array that way it will just add the question arrays to the correct subarray.

```
foreach($q_list as $q){
    $res[$q['subject_id']][] = $q;
}

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/HnlYW